# Opacity toggle three (or more) DIV

Tags: toggle, opacity

```
<div id="rotator">
  <p id="1">Some Text 1</p>
  <p id="1">Some Text 2</p>
  <p id="1">Some Text 3</p>
</div>
```

They are presented in a row. All I want is automatically cycle the three text by toggling opacity, ie. at first text 1 is opacity 1, and test 2 and 3 are opacity .5. Then after 5 seconds or so, text 2 is opacity 1, and text 1 and three are opacity .5... so on in a cycle.

Can someone give me a hint/direction on how to do this in jquery please. Thank you in advance.